# Return formatted string in Python

Tags: python, string, format

I have a string:

```
testString = """ My name is %s
and I am %s years old
and I live in %s"""
```

I have code that finds these three strings that I want to input into testString. How do I do that? In Java I would've done:

```
return String.format(testString, string1, string2, string3)
```

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: I searched for "Python string formatting" and "Python formatted string" on Google. In both cases the relevant documentation was the first hit. Did you find that documentation? Did you run into problems with implementing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I did, but ran into problems. It is fixed now though, thanks to the answer given.

Comment: @hokosha: then *share that information*. Always share your research. If you ran into a problem we can help you fix that problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Alright, I understand. The thing was that I needed to return that string, like I did in my Java example. I realize that I did not really clarify that, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is the version using `%`:

```
print """ My name is %s
and I am %s years old
and I live in %s""" % ('tim', 6, 'new york')
```

and this my preferred version:

```
testString = """ My name is {}
and I am {} years old
and I live in {}""".format(string1, string2, string3)
```

you may want to read https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting .

Comment: Python also supports `%s` style formatting. I'd have hoped the OP had done at least enough research to find the documentation for that.

Comment: you are right. my preferences got in the way... updated.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm pretty sure you cannot type:
"return testString % (string1, string2, string3)" though, right?
However, your preferred version works. Thank you.

Comment: actually yes - you can.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes, my bad. I changed from the '%s' to '{}'. That's why.